# Magento2 : Content Pages are not working on frontend

Tags: php, magento, magento2, content-pages

I was create a FAQ page from admin > content > Pages.When I tried to open this page in frontend its shows `Whoops, our bad...(404 Not found)`.

Page Link : **http://domainname.com/faq**

Cleared all the cache by run this command : **bin/magento cache:flush**

Done reindexing by run this command       : **bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Create Static content by run this command : **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the *Search Engine Optimisation -> URL Key* is set to *faq* and that *Page in websites* is correctly associated with your store view.

If you will still have this issue, please refer to a [bug report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5008) where you can find some workarounds, too.

As an additional test, check that is not a rewrite problem, trying to access the same CMS page with its ID. Ex.: http://domainname.com/cms/page/view/id/**:pageId** .